# XAML Text Box become non editable after applying Control Template

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I wanted rounded edge text box for my windows store app (C++).I have applied control template to XAML Text Box to make it rounded edge.But after running the app I am getting rounded edge but I am not able to edit this TextBox.
I am new to XAML. Plz help me to find out what is missing in this code to make it editable.

Here is the code after making it rounded edge.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,202,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="246" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF00AAA6" IsReadOnly="False">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="2" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TextBox.Resources>
        <TextBox.Template>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="TextBoxControlTemplate1"/>
        </TextBox.Template>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, ControlTemplate does not include ContentElement which causes lack of editable input element.

Check the real style of the TextBox using below link and only change the Related borders "CornerRadius"  property for rounded visual

[TextBox Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I exactlly followed this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc263912.aspx..I dont know why this is not working for me